# Unlock My Phone! November 2018

Tags: knowledge, visual, combinatorics

I had a bit of phone trouble last year, so I had to take a break from puzzle passwords. But once I got it working again I hopped right back in, although this is a pretty easy one.

**What is my phone's password this month?**

> Note:
>
> I just want to say something about the picture associated with this question. The picture is definitely related to the puzzle and I apologize for any confusion. I can be pretty oblivious at times, and I was not meaning any harm nor was I intending to offend anybody, and I did not know about the Holocaust Memorial Day, it is purely coincidental. I simply have an interest in numbers and puzzles, and after watching the movie the Imitation Game I did some research about the Enigma Machine used by the Nazis in WWII. I watched the video linked below (put as a spoiler as it gives away the answer to the puzzle) and found it pretty interesting. I kept the symbol as I did not see any other way to relate it to WWII or this specific Enigma Machine. Sorry for any confusion/hurt I caused. I'll keep it in mind for future puzzles.

Video link:

> [158,962,555,217,826,360,000 (Enigma Machine) - Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2_Q9FoD-oQ)

[image]

Comment: But I wonder if the symbol of Nazi Germany is part of the riddle (I hope so) because I don't know if you know that today in Israel there is a Holocaust Memorial Day, in which over 6 million Jews were murdered

Comment: Simply if it's not part of the puzzle, it may be better to delete the symbol, it can hurt other feelings,I know this is an international site, but maybe that's why it could be a bit of a problem.

Comment: @Tahel: please see my answer.

Comment: @El-Guest :You're probably right .... Just the timing was a bit strange to me.But it seems that only I thought about it so maybe I really got a little carried away.

Comment: There were a variety of different Enigma machines with different total combinations depending on the number of rotors and the plug boards. So I doubt this has a unique answer.

Comment: @Tahel: the choice of symbolism might not have been in the best of tastes, I’ll agree to that. No worries, it was a good comment and maybe one to be wary of when thinking about using such symbolism in a puzzle going forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,

> This appears to be a number related to the Enigma machine. (The symbolism used is a hint as it refers to a country which developed this machine for encryption in World War II.) I found that there are 158,962,555,217,826,360,000 different settings; and 15 billion billion combinations. Is it possible that your password is one of these numbers?

Or potentially,

> 107,458,687,327,250,619,360,000 based on [this site](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~kozdron/Teaching/Cornell/135Summer06/Handouts/enigma.pdf).

Comment: I hope this is the answer.

Comment: Fingers crossed, @PerpetualJ!!

Comment: Yes, the answer was intended to be 158,962,555,217,826,360,000 (the total number of combinations that the Enigma Machine had used by the Germans during WWII). Once again, I apologize. I didn't think about it enough before I posted it.